# OpenVPN server - does dropping previleges affect accessing files at runtime?

Tags: linux, security, permissions, openvpn

In [OpenVPN's hardening article](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/hardening-openvpn-security/), it is recommended that the server daemon drop its privileges after startup on Linux:

> OpenVPN has been very carefully designed to allow root privileges to be dropped after initialization, and this feature should always be used on Linux/BSD/Solaris. Without root privileges, a running OpenVPN server daemon provides a far less enticing target to an attacker.

They recommend that the following directives be set:

```
user nobody
group nobody
```

which I assume mean that the daemon will be running as `nobody` after startup is complete.

However, there are several files that OpenVPN accesses at runtime, [notably the CRL file](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/revoking-certificates/):

> When the crl-verify option is used in OpenVPN, the CRL file will be re-read any time a new client connects or an existing client renegotiates the SSL/TLS connection (by default once per hour). This means that you can update the CRL file while the OpenVPN server daemon is running, and have the new CRL take effect immediately for newly connecting clients.

So naturally I'm worrying if those two features are incompatible - if the daemon drops privileges after startup, how can it read `/etc/openvpn/server/crl.pem` (owner `root:root`, mode `0600`; SELinux enforcing) at runtime?

- If the daemon is indeed unable to access the CRL file at runtime, is there a good way to circumvent this problem?
- If the daemon can access the CRL files at runtime, I would like to know how this is possible.

---

OS is RHEL8.5 x86_64 in case that's relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like a lot of applications that drop privileges, OpenVPN opens various file handles while it still has root, which then persist. Once it has dropped privs, the process is still able to access those handles in the mode they were opened with, for as long they remain open.

A compromise of the `openvpn` process wouldn't expose the file to changes in this case, because the file is (likely, I haven't checked) opened read-only. A new file handle would be required to open it in write mode, which would fail as the process can no longer create one.

Comment: Ah thank you. This makes sense. Is there an official source where this behaviour is documented? Or is this behaviour so commonplace that it has essentially become idiomatic and not worthy of documenting?

Comment: I guess the only _official_ source is the actual source code as it's your only true guide to what's really happening. If you're looking to _understand_ more, then perhaps start with the wiki/man pages on [file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) and the [open() system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html). Once you grok that permissions checks are performed _at those system calls_, this all makes more sense :)

Comment: Dropping privs after opening priv'd ports is definitely a widespread best practice for old school *nix daemons like openvpn and bind.  I'm not sure of an authoritative reference for this habit.